# Operation on String

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

I have a String as "United Kingdom (UK), United States Of America (USA), India (IND)"
I just want values which are in brackets i.e. I want a string "UK,USA,IND" .I am new to java . Please tell me how should I do this

Comment: regex `Matcher` `indexOf()`, `subString()`

Comment: read this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html make a program. if you have any problem in your code then come to SO with your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String example = "United Kingdom (UK), United States Of America (USA), India (IND)";
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\(([^)]+)\\)").matcher(example);
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
        }
    }
```

**Output**

```
UK
USA
IND
```

Comment: Since the questioner is a beginner, a bit more of explanation would be useful…

Comment: totally agree with @Holger

Comment: Although I agree with the above comments, and hoping that nobody will feel offended: The questions does not sound like the asker is searching for *explainations* ...

Comment: Can you pls tell me what will be the pattern if I use [] instead of ().

Answer (score 0):

you may use this:

```
String str = "United Kingdom (UK), United States Of America (USA), India (IND)";
    StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(str, "(,)");
    boolean skip = false;
    while (st2.hasMoreTokens()) {
        if (skip) {
            System.out.println(st2.nextToken());
            skip = false;
        }else{
           String string = st2.nextToken().toString();
            skip = true;
        }
    }
```

Output

```
UK
USA
IND
```

Comment: are you sure this work. Because there is no so such thing `bool` in java second if your skip is false then there is no chance that if block will execute ever. According to me it is a infinite loop without any output